# How do I create a directory?

Tags: nim-lang

I want to check if a directory exists, if not create it.
How can I achieve this? I tried `writeFile` since I wanted to create a file in it, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`existsDir`: http://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#existsDir,string

`createDir`: http://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#createDir,string

So this should work:

```
import os
let dir = "foo"
if not existsDir(dir):
  createDir(dir)
```